# How to write helpers in new Grunt 0.4

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

In an older grund versions I execute helpers like the following:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   grunt.registerMultiTask('taskname', "Grunt task example", function () {
      var result = grunt.helper('helpername', options, data);

      ...
   });

   grunt.registerHelper('helpername', function (options, data) {
      return data;
   });
};
```

How should I execute helpers in new Grunt 0.4 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Upgrading from 0.3 to 0.4](http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4#helpers) page

> **Helpers**
>
> Grunt's helper system has been removed in favor of node `require`. For a concise example on how to share functionality between Grunt plugins, please see [grunt-lib-legacyhelpers](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-legacyhelpers). Plugin authors are encouraged to upgrade their plugins.

Comment: That's not extremely useful. An example of how to create equivalent functionality by using require() would be much more informative. I mean, I've read the upgrading manual and grunt-lib-legacyhelpers docs and I still don't grok how to convert my helpers.